# C# Cloning graph and updating circular references

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let me preface this by stating that I have seen similar posts to this, but none of the solutions have satisfied me and/or applied to C#.

I have a `Graph` class that consists of `Node` and `Connection` objects. The graph contains collections consisting of all of the child Node and Connection objects associated with it. In addition to this, each Node has a collection of Connection objects.

Please note: This is a simplified toy problem. You can view the actual (work-in-progress) production code [here](https://github.com/Wildenhaus/Bostrom/tree/master/Bostrom/ML/NeuralNet). In production, a `Neuron` is a `Node` and an `Axon` is a `Connection`.

```
public class Graph : IDeepCloneable<Graph>
{
  // These are basically just Dictionary<int,object>s wrapped in an ICollection
  public NodeCollection Nodes;
  public ConnectionCollection Connections;

  public Graph Clone()
  {
    return new Graph
    {
      Nodes = this.Nodes.Clone(),
      Connections = this.Connections.Clone()
    };
  }
}

public class Node : IDeepCloneable<Node>
{
  public int Id;
  public NodeConnectionCollection Connections;
  // NodeConnectionCollection is more or less the same as NodeCollection
  // except that it stores Connection objects into '.Incoming' and '.Outgoing' properties

  public Node Clone()
  {
    return new Node
    {
      Id = this.Id,
      Connections = this.Connections.Clone()
    };
  }
}

public class Connection : IDeepCloneable<Connection>
{
  public int Id;
  public Node From;
  public Node To;

  public Connection Clone()
  {
    return new Connection
    {
      Id = this.Id,
      From = this.From.Clone(),
      To = this.To.Clone()
    };
  }
}

public class ConnectionCollection : ICollection<Connection>, IDeepCloneable<ConnectionCollection>
{
  private Dictionary<int, Connection> idLookup;
  private Dictionary<ProjectionKey, Connection> projectionLookup;

  public int Count => idLookup.Count;
  public bool IsReadOnly => false;

  public Add( Connection conn )
  {
    idLookup.Add( conn.Id, conn );
    projectionLookup.Add( new ProjectionKey( conn.From, conn.To ), conn );
  }

  ...

  internal struct ProjectionKey
  {
    readonly intFrom;
    readonly int To;
    readonly int HashCode;

    public ProjectionKey( int from, int to )
    {
      From = from;
      To = to;
      HashCode = ( 23 * 397 + from ) * 397 + to;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() { return HashCode; }
  }
}

public class NodeCollection : ICollection<Node>, IDeepCloneable<NodeCollection>
{
  private Dictionary<int, Node> nodes;
  private Dictionary<int, InputNode> inputNodes;
  private Dictionary<int, InnerNode> innerNodes;
  private Dictionary<int, OutputNode> outputNodes;

  ...

  public Node this[ int id ]
  {
    get => nodes[ id ];
  }

}
```

Each of these objects support deep cloning, with the main idea being that consuming classes can call `Clone()` on child classes and work down the stack that way.

However, this is not viable in production. A call to `Graph.Clone()` will clone the `NodeCollection` and `ConnectionCollection` fields, which will clone each `Node` and `Connection` instance stored within them, which will each clone other referencing child elements.

A common solution seems to be storing the Ids of each child object and then rebuilding the references when all cloning is complete. However, as far as I am aware, this would require a reference to parent objects and tightly couple the data structure.

I am very puzzled at how to properly approach this. **I require a reasonable amount of performance**, as my application (a genetic algorithm) performs cloning constantly, **but in this case I am more interested in finding a robust design pattern or implementation that will allow me to perform deep cloning of this graph structure while stashing a lot of the gruntwork behind the scenes.**

Is there any design pattern that will allow me to clone this data structure as-is while updating circular references and maintaining its integrity?

Comment: The sample you have is very confusing - edges are cloned twice (once by graph and then by each node). Just don't clone edges in nodes and you are all set... Or you graph object is really not what one would expect and contains just references to some of nodes?

Comment: I tried to model this and think I can see where you are going, this is an old issue that ORMs have struggled with for a long time, the answer that really helped was to reduce or remove the dependency on the Ids for linking and rely instead on the direct object references. In my model it all works, so it's hard to speculate on your issue, if you provide the implementation of the two collections and an example of how you have created a simple graph that you want to clone, then we can help more.

Comment: Further to this, the graph holding a collection of links, as well as the nodes holding their own collection of links is a recipe for disaster, especially given that the node is has a many:many relationship through the connection class. Change the model such that the nodes do not hold their own cloned copy of the connections, but instead reference the graph for all the connections between the nodes then the cloning process is more straight forward.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller The redundant storing of connections and nodes ultimately aids with the backing genetic algorithm. It requires picking random elements and performing random modifications to that element. It can be done without redundancy, but is easier with it. I've updated my original post with some insight on the collections, but [it might be easier to just look at the actual code](https://github.com/Wildenhaus/Bostrom/tree/master/Bostrom/ML/NeuralNet). In production, `Neuron` = `Node` and `Axon` = `Connection`. I'll add a link to the original post as well.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to change your approach to the problem from cloning to recreating. I've dealt with a resembling problem, where I was saving a graph user created manually from the user interface, and then upon an import of saved graph I was recreating it. It sounds almost the same if you think about it.

So the solution I came up with was serializing the graph from a central control (considering you are modifying graphs with an heuristic I assume you have central control over the graph). Even if you don't have a central control over the graph I believe it can be traversed in a way to get all the information.

In the simplest form a graph is a collection of neighborhood information.

Can be directed or undirected as well

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
3 -> 2
```

So if you can come up with a way to generate a list like this, after just tweaking this simple list, you can create your new graph.

Or another approach would be to list your nodes with their neighbors like below,

```
1, [2,3]
3, [2]
```

This would even be simpler to recreate the graph in my opinion.

Here is the [file](https://github.com/tolgaevcimen/SELFSIM/blob/master/VisualInterface/GraphPersistancy/GraphPersister.cs) from the project I applied this approach if you are curious about - I don't think it would be a reference for the answer or question though.

Comment: Absolutely, due to the deep interlinking between nodes we should not be attempting to "clone" at all, but to re-create instead.